# Is it possible to define types dynamically in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'am getting an array of strings from the server (available image sizes), and I'd like to generate an object out of that array, like this:

[el1,el2...] = { el1:'el1',el2:'el2'...}

So this way when I'am trying to access some value I can see an actual values in the code instead of using indexes.
But I don't know what elements my array will consist of, so is there a way of defining types dynamically or maybe another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Typescript is JavaScript, with _static_ typing. Do you know what the array type is on the server?

Comment: It's an array of strings, but strings values can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to transform an array of strings into an object whose key-value pairs correspond to each value in the array. You can do that with a function like this:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM4HkBGArAptRAClSgCcYwBzVALkRPKoG0BdASjoCV85SATADwMKlADT0yIgHyIA3gFgAUIkQQEJRKVyoQAGyhce-IZKrjhVGQF45AXwDcSlcF5E1YDQ0RxgExtTZNbT0oJgYWRBsGR2UgqBBSJC0dfRjbJSV3DWRSUmQAT0jEJgByXF0ARhLxMt0AJhKWGKyobxwitCw8aEIcvPy2ZvU4XVwAOl04SkI4HEHEAHoFqxlZRHKKugAiDa3xcrrtg63EdMUgA)

```ts
function asObject (strings: string[]): Record<string, string> {
  const result: Record<string, string> = {};
  for (const str of strings) result[str] = str;
  return result;
}

const array = ['el1', 'el2'];
const obj = asObject(array);
console.log(obj); //=> { el1: "el1", el2: "el2" }
```

Comment: Yes, but I want my result object to be of a type : { el1 : string, el2 : string }. Like this result: Record <CurrentElement, CurrentElementType> = {}

Comment: TypeScript is statically-typed (evaluated at compile-time). Because you are getting the strings at runtime, it isn’t possible to derive string literal properties from that data.